# Php and MySQL with Highchart

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

Somebody can help me. I'm new in php and highcharts. I tried to populate my chart using mysql and php, but when I tried to run it, the chart didn't appear, I only sse a blank web page. And there's no error appeared.

Her's my codes (sorry for messy code):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>

       <script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

</head>

        <body>

    <?php
include "config.php";

$SQL1 =     "SELECT * FROM pos";

$result1 = mysql_query($SQL1);
$data1 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
   $data1[] = $row['name'];
   $data2[] = $row['Qty'];

}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            margin: [ 50, 50, 100, 80]
        },
        title: {
            text: 'List of POS'
        },
    credits: {
    enabled: false
    },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [<?php echo join($data1, "','"); ?>],
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                align: 'right',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'No. of Ticket'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
    layout: 'vertical',
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        align: 'left',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: 50,
                        y: 35,
                        floating: true,
                        shadow: true
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<b>{point.y:.1f} tickets</b>',
        },
     plotOptions: {
                            column: {
                                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                                        borderWidth: 0
                                    }
                        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Qty',
            data: ['<?php echo join($data2, "','"); ?>'],
    dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                x: 4,
                y: 10,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black',

                }
            }
        }]
    });
});

    </script>

   <div id="container" style="min-width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
    </html>
```

And here's my config.php

```
 <?php
 $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
 $mysql_user = "root";
 $mysql_password = "";
 $mysql_database = "pos";
 $prefix = "";
 $bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not  connect database");
 mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");

  ?>
```

Comment: If you view the source of the webpage your are trying to display this, does it show all the JavaScript correctly? That's an easy way to find out if you have a php problem or a JavaScript one

Comment: How does your json look like? can show that what actually is being written?

Comment: I don't have json file, instead direct coding into mysql and php

Comment: Take look at the similiar topic http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-database. I advice to return json in your php file, and then load json by jquery. You will be ensured that all values are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blank pages usually mean syntax errors.  You should switch [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on.

The errors are in the use of your `echo` statements where you construct the json.  The error is that you are missing semi colons in both the `echo` statements.

Replace `<?php echo join($data1, ',') ?>` with `<?php echo join($data1, ','); ?>`

Similarly for `$data2`:

Replace `<?php echo join($data2, ',') ?>` with `<?php echo join($data2, ','); ?>`

Another improvement you could make in the following block:

```
    <?php
include "config.php";

$SQL1 =     "SELECT * FROM pos";

$result1 = mysql_query($SQL1);
$data1 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
   $data1[] = $row['name'];
}

$result2 = mysql_query($SQL1);
$data2 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
   $data2[] = $row['Qty'];
}
?>
```

Instead of executing query twice to build two arrays, you could get rid of one of the queries and build both the arrays from the same query result:

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$SQL1 =     "SELECT * FROM pos";

$result1 = mysql_query($SQL1);

$data1 = array();
$data2 = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
   $data1[] = $row['name'];
   $data2[] = $row['Qty'];
}
?>
```

**Note:** [The `php` `mysql` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, you should be using either MySQLi or PDO_MySQL.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: I already did what you said, but nothing change. And I encountered new error --- Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 166

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config\Container.php on line 111

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\otrs\chart\graphs\pos\index.php on line 22

Comment: That error tells me that either the connection to the database is not successful or the query failed.  Can you post your `Config.php`?

Comment: Here's my config.php -- <?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "pos";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");

?>

Comment: I put the config.php in the folder where my index.php place and the error was gone, but when I reload the webpage, I got a blank web page again

Comment: Please update your question with the updated code you're using.

Comment: @user3098728, wrap `<?php echo join($data1, "','"); ?>` with single quotes like you've done for `<?php echo join($data2, "','"); ?>`

Comment: I did that, but nothing happened

Answer (score 2):

Please Try Example as below. I think it can help you

**SQL Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `month` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=118 ;


INSERT INTO `sales` (`id`, `month`, `amount`) VALUES
(24, 'Apr', '15'),
(25, 'May', '40'),
(26, 'Jun', '26'),
(27, 'Jul', '31'),
(28, 'Aug', '39'),
(29, 'Sep', '25'),
(30, 'Oct', '27'),
(31, 'Nov', ' 32'),
(32, 'Dec', NULL);
```

Here we have Create new table and insert some data in it. Now Data will look as below

[image: Mysql]

**index.php**

```
<head>
    <meta name="Gopal Joshi" content="Highchart with Mysql" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Highchart with Mysql Database</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/setup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
    <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <div id="sales" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
```

**setup.js**

```
var chart;
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var cursan = {
   chart: {
    renderTo: 'sales',
    defaultSeriesType: 'area',
    marginRight: 10,
    marginBottom: 20
   },
   title: {
    text: 'Highchart With Mysql',
   },
   subtitle: {
    text: 'www.spjoshis.blogspot.com',
   },
   xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
   },
   yAxis: {
    title: {
     text: 'Average'
    },
    plotLines: [{
     value: 0,
     width: 1,
     color: '#808080'
    }]
   },
   tooltip: {
       crosshairs: true,
                shared: true
   },
   legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -10,
    y: 30,
    borderWidth: 0
   },

            plotOptions: {

                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',  
                    marker: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                }
            },

         series: [{
       color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
    name: 'Test Colomn',
                marker: {
                    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    lineWidth: 3,
                    lineColor: null // inherit from series
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: 0,
                    color: '#666666',
                    align: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: -10,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '9px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                        textShadow: '0 0 0px black'
                    }
                }
   }],
        }

        //Fetch MySql Records
        jQuery.get('js/data.php', null, function(tsv) {
   var lines = [];
   traffic = [];
   try {
    // split the data return into lines and parse them
    tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
    jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
     line = line.split(/\t/);
     date = line[0] ;
                                        amo=parseFloat(line[1].replace(',', ''));
                                        if (isNaN(amo)) {
                                                   amo = null;
                                        }
     traffic.push([
      date,
      amo
     ]);
    });
   } catch (e) {  }
   cursan.series[0].data = traffic;
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart(cursan);
  });
 });
```

s will import data from `mysql` from `data.php` and add to chart which is create previously in js.

**data.php**

```
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
$result=mysql_query('select * from sales order by id');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['month'] . "\t" . $row['amount']. "\n";
}
```

our chart is fully loaded .with mysql records and output will look li below

**Output** [image: output]

its example of area chart, you can change type of chart by changing defaultSeriesType: 'area'

[Click Here](http://sgeek.org/create-chart-using-mysql-highcharts/) for more Example with source.

Answer (score 1):

I think your supposed to have single quotes around this

```
categories: [<?php echo join($data1, ',') ?>],
```

Should be

```
categories: ['<?php echo join($data1, ',') ?>'],
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is an old thread, this might have nothing to do with Highcharts, I'v just noted the final phrase in your error message:

```
"...Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
in C:\xampp\htdocs\otrs\chart\graphs\pos\index.php on line 22"
```

tipically has to do with a query that fails returning FALSE instead of a rowset. You should take a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-mysqli-result-boolea).